# Removal of NA's in specific columns R

Tags: r, dplyr, na

Although many questions have been asked like this at this forum but I've gone through most of them and my problem is a bit different. I have a dataframe:

```
A  B  C  key
NA NA NA LIMA
3  1  NA GAMMA
NA NA NA SIGNA
NA 2  NA BETA
NA NA 4  SIGMA
```

And I want to remove rows which have NA on the feature set (A, B, C). The key is never empty and will never have missing values. So the resulting frame would look like:

```
A  B  C  key
3  1  NA GAMMA
NA 2  NA BETA
NA NA 4  SIGMA
```

The structure of a similar dataframe can be copied from below

```
structure(list(A = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), B = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), C = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), D = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), E = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), F = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), G = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), H = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), I = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), J = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), K = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), L = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), M = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), N = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), O = c(0, 2, NA, NA, 1, 1), P = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Q = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), R = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), S = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), T = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), key = c("django", 
"lima", "bravo", "alpha", "gamma", 
"meta")), row.names = c(100077L, 93143L, 244634L, 25010L, 
117228L, 147983L), class = "data.frame")
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `rowSums` :

```
cols <- c('A', 'B','C')
df[rowSums(!is.na(df[cols])) != 0, ]
```

Using `dplyr` you could use `across` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(Reduce(`|`, across(all_of(cols), ~!is.na(.))))
```

Comment: since OP has more columns than just A B and C, in his sample data, can we have some another method to input these col values instead of storing them in `cols` vector?  I'm just curious to know

Comment: There are ways to capture those columns but OP needs to clarify how the columns are stored in their data. For example based on position we can do `cols <- 1:3`. If their columns have some pattern we can use `grep` to get the index of the columns.

Comment: My original columns all started with 'S' so I just used a ```starts_with('S')``` to compile my column names.

Answer (score 1):

```
## generate a list of feature columns however you like
feature_cols = c("A", "B", "C")
## keep rows where there are fewer NAs (in the feature columns) than feature columns
new_data = old_data[rowSums(is.na(old_data[feature_cols])) < length(feature_cols), ]
```